# How do I get the <td> values in a row onClick

Tags: reactjs, html-table

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import './SearchDataTable.css'

const SearchDataTable = (props) => {

    const serverData = props.serverData

    const handleRowClick = (rowValue) => {
        console.log(rowValue)
    }
     return(    
        <div>
        <Table bordered>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Affected</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 {props.sortData ? (serverData.sort((a,b) => a.quantity - b.quantity).map(data =>  (
                <tr className="table-row" onClick={(e) => handleRowClick(e)} key={data.quantity}>
                    <td>{data.affectedOn}</td> 
                    <td>{data.type}</td> 
                    <td>{data.quantity}</td> 
                </tr>
            ))):(serverData.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity).map(data =>  (
                <tr key={data.quantity}>
                    <td>{data.affectedOn}</td> 
                    <td>{data.type}</td> 
                    <td>{data.quantity}</td> 
                </tr>
            ))) }
            </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
    )
}

export default SearchDataTable;
```

From the above code I tried getting the corresponding `<td>` value onClicking the row. I added the onClick on `<tr>` and tried, but failed in doing it. I need some help in solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing e to handleRowClick, pass the data.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import './SearchDataTable.css'

const SearchDataTable = (props) => {

    const serverData = props.serverData

    const handleRowClick = (rowValue) => {
        console.log(rowValue)
    }
     return(    
        <div>
        <Table bordered>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Affected</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 {props.sortData ? (serverData.sort((a,b) => a.quantity - b.quantity).map((data, index) =>  (
                <tr className="table-row" onClick={() => handleRowClick(data)} key={index}>
                    <td>{data.affectedOn}</td> 
                    <td>{data.type}</td> 
                    <td>{data.quantity}</td> 
                </tr>
            ))):(serverData.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity).map((data, index) =>  (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{data.affectedOn}</td> 
                    <td>{data.type}</td> 
                    <td>{data.quantity}</td> 
                </tr>
            ))) }
            </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
    )
}

export default SearchDataTable;
```

Also replaced the key on the rows with index instead of quanity, since it seems like quantity would not be a unique identifier. Ideally, you would have something else that is unique, like an id property, but index can be okay if not.

Comment: Also, may want to apply the same onClick to the second case in the ternary, since I assume sort order does not effect whether the row is clickable.

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleRowClick = (data) => {
    console.log(data.affectedOn, data.type, data.quantity)
}

....
<tr onClick={() => this.handleClick(data)}>
  <td>{data.affectedOn}</td> 
  <td>{data.type}</td> 
  <td>{data.quantity}</td> 
</tr>
....
```